# code to run my application in system tray

Tags: c#, .net

i need the procedure how to make my application in system tray like gtalk . my application should run in the background when my system starts

Comment: Check out the `NotifyIcon` control in the Common Controls group.

Comment: i developed a reminder application. i need my application should be there in system tray when  system sarts

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to put an .net application in system tray when minimized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76079/how-to-put-an-net-application-in-system-tray-when-minimized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` is the class to use, mess with it a bit and return here if anything else is unclear

Comment: thank you MR.ss kain . what my requirement is if i closed my application by clicking X .it should not exit from  system tray.like gtalk.

Comment: register for `FormClosing` event and in `FormClosingEventArgs` param set `Cancel` to `true`