# Having the application minimize to the system tray when button is clicked?

Tags: c#, tooltip, system-tray, minimize

How can I have my application minimize itself to the system tray in WindowsXP/Vista?

I'm also looking for a way to have a message display itself when the mouse is hovered on the icon. Is it possible to have two lines in the pop up balloon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you mean minimize to the System tray because you have talked about icons and message ballons?

The  following code will set up a tray icon:

```
private void SetUpTrayIcon()
{
    notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
    notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Ballon minimize text";
    notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Ballon minimize title";
    notifyIcon.Text = "Icon hover text";
    notifyIcon.Icon = new  System.Drawing.Icon(
               System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                   .GetManifestResourceStream("MyIcon.ico"));
    notifyIcon.Click += new EventHandler(HandlerToMaximiseOnClick);
}
```

To show the icon in the tray (you may want to do this on the window state change event for example, do something like the following:

```
if (notifyIcon != null)
{
    notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
}
```

To display a ballon on mouse hover you want to use the same code as above possibly in the mousemove for the icon.

Note: ShowBalloonTip is overloaded if you want to change the message at different points. The message the balloon displays will respect newlines eg Environment.NewLine can be added to it.

Answer (score 3):

try

to minimize

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

to minimize to tray see this

[What's the proper way to minimize to tray a C# WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-winforms-app)

Bye

Comment: This only minimizes it to the lower bar. I want it to become a little icon next to the clock, can you help? :P

Comment: @Papuccino1: you mean you want it to appear in the system tray.

Comment: Yeah, I got mixed up in terms. :D Care to help?

Answer (score 0):

The popup balloon will display whatever is shown in the form's title bar (which is the form's .Text property).  I don't know of any way to make it multi-lined (if there is a way, it's sure to be complicated and probably not worth the trouble).

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995195/writing-a-windows-system-tray-application-with-net) gives some answers to the basic question.  Your toolbox contains a control called **NotifyIcon** - use this to place an icon in the system tray.