# How do I minimize a WinForms application to the notification area?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, notifyicon

I want to minimize a C# WinForms app to system tray. I've tried this:

[Having the application minimize to the system tray when button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297028/having-the-application-minimize-to-the-system-tray-when-button-is-clicked). The first time I minimize it, it's nowhere to be found on the screen - taskbar/above taskbar/tray.

If i hit alt tab, I can see my app there; if I alt tab into it and minimize it again, it shows up above the taskbar:

[image: minimize]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What about the option of hiding the form when minimized then showing once you click on the tray icon?

In the form resize event, do the check there and hide the form

```
   private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Then when clicking on the taskbar icon just restore it.

```
    private void notifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) to your form. You can then use the [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.click.aspx) event of the NotifyIcon to have it set the `Visible` property on your `Form` to `true` again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an icon on NotifyIcon for it to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property `ShowInTaskbar = true` of your Form. It automatically minimizes to the task bar.