# How does Windows force "minimized" state from a desktop shortcut?

Tags: c#, winforms, shortcut-file

I have an application that is designed to minimize to the system tray.  No issues there.

The problem I am having is that I cannot determine what Windows is doing to force the minimized state when I set up a desktop shortcut to that executable and launch it, such as:

[image]

I put some debug outputs in the form's constructor and launched via the shortcut.  I get no command line arguments and a check of `WindowState` yields `Normal`.  Yet the app starts minimized to the taskbar.

However, that's the rub:  I want it to start minimized to the system tray, just as it would if the form were on-screen and the user minimized it.  Not all the time, just when a "minimize" shortcut is used, or when the user clicks Minimize on the form, of course.

**EDIT:**  for the curious...my initial testing was flawed because I checked in the constructor.  Placing the test in the `Load` method produced a `Minimized` state, to which I could then react and call my code to perform the "minimize-to-tray".

Comment: I don't get the downvotes either.

Comment: have you looked at any working examples that have been posted on the internet as well as `SO` also in your code are you setting the WindowState.. for example `1this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;` [App Minimize to Tray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray) I think that you need this one here I just re-read your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140627/minimize-to-tray

Comment: @DJKRAZE Please read the entirety of the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray

Comment: I figured it out.  Just checking too soon.  Apparently the `WindowState` isn't forced to `Minimized` until at least the `Load` event.  Checking too soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is starting the process with parameters to minimize the main window.

In C#, you can do the same by setting [WindowStyle (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at `ProcessStartInfo` for use in `Process.Start()`.

In the native world, you would use the [CreateProcess (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API and pass a [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), setting `wShowWindow` to `SW_MINIMIZE`.

To query the window state, use [GetWindowInfo (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), look at `dwStyle` and check if `WS_MINIMIZE`is set. In C#, this should be in [Form.WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).