# C# Windows Form WindowState vs Shortcut's Run property

Tags: c#, forms, shortcut, windowstate

I have a C# Windows Form application lauching an instance of a form upon execution using the default code:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main () {
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

If I use the default value "Normal" for WindowState property on Form1, I'm able to create a shortcut for the application and set the Run property to Normal, Minimized or Maximized and it's gonna be respected.

However, if the application is NOT run through a shortcut, I want it to be maximized, by default. But if I set WindowState property to Maximized, the shortcut's Run property is no longer respected at all.

Is there a way to handle both cases?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257808/how-does-windows-force-minimized-state-from-a-desktop-shortcut

Comment: @dotctor Thanks but after review, it's not a duplicate of that question. I also need to have a "default" windowstate to Maximized instead of Normal when the application is NOT started through a shurtcut, like dbl-clicking the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial way of detecting the shortcut setting. By partial I mean this method does not seem to work for the `Normal Window` option in the shortcut if you set the `WindowState` to something else then `Normal` in the `OnLoad` event. It works however for `Minimized` & `Maximized` shortcut options. *Maybe someone else will be able to explain this.*

Form-class:

```
bool windowStateSetByShortcut = false;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    /*WM_SIZE*/
    if (m.Msg == 0x0005)
    {
        // This will be set to true if the shortcut uses the Maximized or Minimized
        // options because then it runs before OnLoad.
        windowStateSetByShortcut = true;     
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{    
    if (!windowStateSetByShortcut)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```