# Programming Scary Screamer on C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in c# and trying to develop Scary Screamer Application. It is an joke  windows forms application which is running on the PC and invisible in taskbar.
There is timer running in this application. If system datetime.now.minute = 15
It should play scary sound and show scary picture on the screen. After 1-2 seconds picture should disappear from the screen.
But i am stuck and don't know how to make picture disappear. Any Ideas how to do that?
Below is my code:

```
namespace screamer2
{        
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SoundPlayer pla = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._3);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
            this.Left = 0;
            this.Top = 0;

            this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width/2;
            this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height/2;
            this.TopMost = true;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Minute == 15)
            {
                BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1;

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                pla.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `BackgroundImage = null;`?

Comment: After you have played the sound and waited, set the background image back to Null?

Comment: i'd tried already, but if i did that, then picture not appearing at all.

Comment: you might want to try to minimize your window by setting `FormWindowState.Minimized` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317033/how-do-i-minimize-a-winforms-application-to-the-notification-area

Comment: @Nikolai Are you setting the background image back to null after your thread.sleep?

Comment: @Stefan H Thanks for reply, i have tried to set background back to null, but then picture not appearing at all

Comment: @ironstone13  Thanks for reply, but this also not working, because window get minimized immediately , even if i do
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

Comment: You realize that none of us know what "Scary Screamer" is and therefore putting it in your question title adds no value?

Comment: Noted, next time i will be more accurate with titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to set image once in `Form1_Load` and then control any showing and hiding of window using `Form.Opacity` variable. I have tested the code below and should work as you wanted.

```
 SoundPlayer pla = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources._3);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
        this.Left = 0;
        this.Top = 0;
        this.Opacity = 0; //This line added 

        this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2;
        this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2;

        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources._1; //We set the image once here

        this.TopMost = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Minute == 15)
        {
            this.Opacity = 1; //We show the window
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            pla.Play();
            this.Opacity = 0; //We hide the window
        }
    }
```