# Minimize my winform application into system tray

Tags: c#

I try to Minimize my winform application into system tray and when minimize my application it still open in task bar and not in system tray and close automatic after few seconds
i have added `NotifyIcon` control and register to `Resize` event:

```
    private void MainWin_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (FormWindowState.Normal == this.WindowState)
        {
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to fix it ? (did you read what i have wrote ?)

Comment: you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297028/having-the-application-minimize-to-the-system-tray-when-button-is-clicked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-sharp-winforms-app

Comment: In the first link: it mention to register to window state change event  - what exactly this event ? (i didn't find this event)

Comment: You've only stated what are you trying to achieve. You did not provide any information about what's wrong with your code or if you get any errors. Also please use search button and do not duplicate questions, that were previously explained. You can find window state change in the events panel or use it manually in the form's body same way as you do with your `MainWin_Resize` method. It's just better to only fire the method on state changes instead of size changes. TBH I'm not even sure if Resize event occurs on state change.

Comment: i don't know that wrong with my cod but my application is closed automatic after few seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (this.WindowState)
        {
            case FormWindowState.Maximized:
                this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                break;
            case FormWindowState.Minimized:
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                break;
            case FormWindowState.Normal:
                this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```