# Hide a form to the system tray

Tags: vb.net, systray

I'm posting this here since it took a lot of time for me to understand how the whole thing works when trying to hide a form in the systray.

My question basically was: How can I hide a windows form running operations to the system tray?

CFP.

Comment: A C# duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/
Some of the answers have links to VB.NET codes though.

Comment: Posted an answer to my own question : )
CFP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to show the from that you will need to hide. Make sure you don't make it Modal.

```
Dim F as New MyForm
Form.Show()
```

Then, create a notification icon, and make associate the following with its click function:

```
Me.Visible = Not Me.Visible
```

Careful though. If you first showed the form using `ShowDialog`, then setting `Visible = False` will close the form and destroy it (which can get nasty if you were using a separate thread which communicated with the form, for example).