# C# Creating A Program That Runs In The Background?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the proper way to minimize to tray a C# WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-sharp-winforms-app)

How can I create a program that runs in the background, and can be accessed via the Windows' "Notification Area" (Where the date and time are in the lower right hand corner)?

In other words, I want to be able to create a program that runs and can toggle between having a display window and not having a display window.

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918/whats-the-proper-way-to-minimize-to-tray-a-c-winforms-app/47743#47743 in a related question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Drag and drop a `NotifyIcon` and a `ContextMenuStrip`.
2. Set de NotifyIcon's context menu to the one you added
3. Add 2 menuitems (e.g. Restore, Exit)
4. Set the Form event `resize` and do the following check

   ```
   private void MyForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) this.Hide();
       else this.Show();
   }

   // you could also restore the window with a
   // double click on the notify icon
   private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       this.Show();
       this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
   }
   ```

For a example can download [this project](http://www.4shared.com/file/NknXPIbM/WallpaperSelectorSource.html)

Don't worry about the right click event, the `NotifyIcon` will automatically detect it and show the `ContextMenu`