# Proper way of activating my MainForm from a NotifyIcon if it wasn't focused already

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, trayicon

I just want to replace the task bar button of my winforms application by a tray notification icon. That means, if the user left-clicks the icon, the form should be activated if it wasn't focused, otherwise minimized or hidden.

I read lots and lots of articles about properly using a `NotifyIcon`, and it seems I have to accept a hackish solution. So, what's the most proper way?

I got it mostly to run, but now I'm stuck at detecting if my form was active already - because when clicking the icon, the form looses focus, so I cannot check the `Focused` property.

The following code does not yet solve this, so if the form was just hidden by other windows, you have to click 2 times, because the first click minimizes.

How can it be improved?

```
    private void FormMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            Hide();
    }

    private void notifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                Show();
                Activate();
            }
            else {
                Hide();
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }
    }
```

(I also don't understand why the `Click` event fires on right-clicking, which already opens the context menu in my case...)

(And of course it would be nice to have a proper minimize animation, but there are other questions here, where this wasn't really solved)

(I know I said `Focused`, but if the form was already fully visible (but maybe not focused), and the user clicks the tray icon, he most likely wants to hide it)

Comment: You will have to resort to hacks since the moment before you click on the NotifyIcon, your form will be deactivated.  Lots of hacks trying to start a timer in the MouseMove event and try to create a MouseLeave event connected to that icon, but none are reliable, because windows does not provide the rectangle bounds of your icon.

Comment: @LarsTech then it's maybe better to start a timer on deactivation of the form... But I would not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LarsTech suggested a hack using a timer, and this works, thanks, but I still hope for better solutions or improvements.

Maybe interesting: I also hack-solved part of the animation problem - when there is no taskbar button, the animation originates from where the minimized form is located. You can make it visible by calling `Show()` after minimizing. It sits in the lower left of the screen and it is not possible to move it by setting i.e. the `Left` property. So I used winapi directly and it works!
Unfortunately only for the restore animation, because I don't know how to set the minimized position before minimizing. `Hide()` disables the animation anyway, so I would have to delay it...

That all is so disappointing! Why is there no nice solution? I can never be sure if it will work in every scenario. For example on one machine it worked well with a 100ms timer, but on another I needed 200ms. So I suggest to have a least 500ms.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, 
    int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

private void FormMain_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!ShowInTaskbar && WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) {
        Hide();
        //Move the invisible minimized window near the tray notification area
        if (!MoveWindow(Handle, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left
                + Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width - 100,
                Top, Width, Height, false))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}

private void notifyIcon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized || !timer.Enabled) {
            Show();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            Activate();
        }
        else {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            //FormMain_Resize will be called after this
        }
}

private void FormMain_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}

//other free goodies not mentioned before...

private void taskbarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowInTaskbar = !ShowInTaskbar;
    taskbarToolStripMenuItem.Checked = ShowInTaskbar;
}

private void priorityToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set the process priority from ToolStripMenuItem.Tag
    //Normal = 32, Idle = 64, High = 128, BelowNormal = 16384, AboveNormal = 32768
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass
        = (ProcessPriorityClass)int.Parse((sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Tag.ToString());
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in contextMenuStrip.Items)
        if (item.Tag != null)
            item.Checked = item.Equals(sender);
}

private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}
```